# datepicker input field required is not required

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I have a datepicker input field in my form that should be required. I made the input field required like this:

```
<div class="col-md-8 animate-box">
    <div class="bootstrap-iso">
        <div class="form-group"> <!-- Date input -->
            <input class="form-control" id="date" name="date" 
                   placeholder="Afhalen. Donderdag 17-19u. Zaterdag 09-16u. Minstens 1 week op voorhand reserveren." 
                   type="text" readonly='true' required data-readonly/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

unfortunately, it isn't required!?

This is the code where I build the datepicker, but I think that's not the problem:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var date_input=$('input[name="date"]'); //our date input has the name "date"
        var container=$('.bootstrap-iso form').length>0 ? $('.bootstrap-iso form').parent() : "body";
        date_input.datepicker({
            format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
            container: container,
            autoclose: true,
            startDate: '+1w',
            daysOfWeekHighlighted: "4,6",
            daysOfWeekDisabled: "0,1,2,3,5",
            orientation: "auto",
        })
    })
</script>
```

I use:

```
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- jQuery Easing -->
<script src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: What you want exactly? can you please explain your question in brief?

Answer (score 1):

You can't make an input readonly AND required.
Make the datepicker popup when they click the field too and nobody will type in there.

If they do you can make a keyup function to erase the input.

Comment: of can i do the "keyup function to erase the input"? thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#your element id").prop('required',true);
```

OR

```
$("#your element id").attr("required", true);
```